# SOSL Query: Getting different number of records while searching with 1234* and abcd1234*

Tags: community, sosl, dynamic-sosl, indexing

I have a community page. It has a search box and a list view to display the search result. Below is the Query I'm building: (It will search in 15M total records)

```
List<List<sObject>> searchList = [FIND '1234*' IN ALL  FIELDS RETURNING Service_visit__c 
                                  (Account__r.Name, Account__r.Location__c, OId, Start_Date__c, Address1__c, City__c, State__c, Report_Type__c ORDER BY Start_Date__c DESC LIMIT 200 )
                               ];
```

Above SOSL is resulting in less record assuming 30 counts.

But When I'm searching with some other string 'abcd 1234*', It's resulting in many records (150 records):

```
List<List<sObject>> searchList = [FIND 'abcd1234*' IN ALL  FIELDS RETURNING Service_visit__c 
                                  (Account__r.Name, Account__r.Location__c, OId, Start_Date__c, Address1__c, City__c, State__c, Report_Type__c ORDER BY Start_Date__c DESC LIMIT 200 )
                               ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are simply different queries that match different result sets.

SOSL does not perform substring matching (matches that start within a token). `1234*` will match any token beginning with `1234`, but it won't match, for example, `abcd1234`. Conversely, `abcd1234*` will match `abcd123456`, but it will not match `123456`.

There are some examples demonstrating this principle in the [`FIND` section](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm#topic-title) of the SOQL and SOSL Reference:

> Asterisks match zero or more characters at the middle or end of your search term. For example, a search for `john*` **finds items that start with john**, such as, `john`, `johnson`, or `johnny`. A search for `mi* meyers` finds items with `mike meyers` or `michael meyers`.

Emphasis mine. Note how the wildcards apply only in the middle or at the end of a token that is part of the search term.